# Concat two columns in sql query Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to search into users table by fullname which needs to concat two columns firstname and lastname and compare to the given value

```
 User::where(function($usersSearchQuery) use ($user,$fullName){
  $usersSearchQuery->whereRaw("CONCAT('first_name', 'last_name') = ?", [$firstName]); })->get();
```

i got this error

> message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (1 = 1 and 1 = 1 and `full_name` LIKE sdfdf%))"

Comment: i replaced it with selectRaw() still the same error full_name is undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function in User model itself.

```
public $appends = ['full_name'];

public function getFullNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
}

// You can call it like this from controller or from view
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $fullName[] = $user->full_name;
}
```

Comment: Sandeep you are a little off. I have edited your answer to use the attributes as indicated in laravel documentation. Please wait for the edit to be approved.

Comment: the function already exists ! but how to do it in query because that's not optimised at all to add an additional code just for getting all the fullnames

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your select to `->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name"))`, after that, it should work. Or (if you are using Laravel 8), you can directly use [`selectRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw).

If it is still not working, change `where` with [`whereRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#whereraw-orwhereraw) like `->whereRaw('full_name LIKE "?%"', [$fullName]);`. So have both `selectRaw` and `whereRaw`.

```php
User::where(function ($usersSearchQuery) use ($user, $fullName) {
    return $usersSearchQuery->selectRaw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name")
        ->whereRaw('full_name LIKE "?%"', [$fullName]);
})->get();
```

Comment: i update the code please check it , i got this error : message: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Julianne% full_name)' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `users` where (1 = 1 and 1 = 1 Julianne% full_name))"

Comment: message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where (1 = 1 and 1 = 1 and full_name LIKE "Julianne%"))"

Answer (score 0):

The error exist in

```
->whereRaw('full_name','LIKE',$fullName.'%');
```

since the query output of the above eloquent query is

```
select CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name from users
where full_name like 'SANDEEP%';
```

In this case the "full_name" attribute is not yet known to the query and it is not a column of users table, so the error says column not found, for this reason it is good to use sub query

```
Select * from (select CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name from users) as u
where full_name like 'SANDEEP%';
```

whose equivalent query is

```
$sub = DB::table('users as u')->selectRaw("u.*, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) as full_name");
$users = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
         ->whereRaw("full_name LIKE '{$fullName}%'")
         ->get();
```

Comment: thank you @Sandeep Dhakal, your code works but it's more optimised to put it all in one query

Comment: Then making a view in database with full_name column, and directly calling the respective modal would be a nice and clean way  to do it in a single line.

Comment: i am using your solution actually it works fine i will accept this answer, there is only one thing it's returning only the fullname in the results how can i return the whole user ? not only fullname

Comment: I have edited the code to get all users data.